# How to fix \i 'file location' query in postgresql command line in windows 10 showing permission denied?

Tags: postgresql

I tried to execute `'\i file_location'` query in postgresql command line.I tried solving it by giving two different file paths i.e `C://Users/public/person.sql`  and `F://data//person.sql` but it didn't work at all showing error as permission denied.

[image]

Comment: Well, give the PostgreSQL server permission.

Answer (score 1):

The path must be specified using slashes (as in your question). If you use backslashes, as in your picture, you will get this `permission denied` error.

==> use slashes.

```sql
\i D:\temp\sel.sql
D:: Permission denied
\i D:/temp/sel.sql
SET
```