# I cannot execute this script after giving permission to everyone on full control on C disk, can anyone solve this?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, command, psql

```
platform=\> \\i C:\\path\\Database\\3_apply_db_changes.sql
C:: Permission denied
platform=\>
```

I can't run this script, theres no way. I gave everyone permission on full control on C disk, and i still have the problem, where could it be that I missed something?

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994174/how-to-fix-i-file-location-query-in-postgresql-command-line-in-windows-10-sho/63994558#63994558) use slashes, not backslashes

Comment: thanks dude, this is embarassing